# Update Inner Join two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

** Table Inputs**

`(id_inpits, name, quantity_inputs)`

**Table Outputs**
`(id_outputs, name_outputs, quantity_outputs, quantity_disponible)

when I want to update the `quantity_output`, and calculate the `quantity_disponbile`

knowing that : `quantity_disponbile = quantity_inputs - quantity_output`

I tried with :

```
if(!empty($_POST['do'])) {

    $m_id = $_POST['id_output'];

    $quantity_outputs = $_POST["quantity_outputs"];

    $sql = $db->query("UPDATE outputs AS o INNER JOIN inputs As i ON i.id_input = o.inputs_id  SET o.quantity_dispo = 'select quantity_inputs from inputs - FROM (select quantity_outputs from outputs )', o.quantity_outputs = '$quantity_outputs'  WHERE o.id_output =' $m_id'"); 

    if(!$sql) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi user3900044, where is your question? Regards!

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion: quantity_disponbile is supposed a calculated field from both table. So split the logic into two: one select query and one update query. The update query just need to update the quantity_output, and the select query can be like:

```
select 
  i.quantity_inputs -  o.quantity_output = quantity_disponible
from output o 
    inner join input i on i.id_inpits = o.inputs_id
```

I don't correct the typo anyway